# N to N relation with attributes and validation data

Tags: forms, symfony

I have three classes to represent a n to n relation with attributes :

- A Product class
- A Tag class
- Product_Tag class

On the add and edit pages of one product, I would like to add or remove tags.
I use the GenemuFormBundle to show tags with the select 2 bundle and so far display is okay.

But when I try to save my form, I have an error because the system tries to save the tags ids in the Product class's "product_tags[]" attribute. I know I should create a new Product_tag object instead, but I don't know how to prevent the link to be saved in the form submission, neither how to get these data in the controller to do the mapping manually.

May someone tell me what is the proper way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an example in the Symfony Cookbook, which should help you moving forward: [Transforming an issue number into an issue entity](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html#harder-example-transforming-an-issue-number-into-an-issue-entity).

Basically you have to create a DataTransformer, which will transform your tag's into string representations and after submitting the form reverse the transformation to get Tag-entities.

You might also be interested in another chapter: [Dynamic form modification](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html).